# PHP Imap_mail_move() Makes "Seen" Message As "Unread"

Tags: php, imap

I'm using imap_mail_move + imap_expunge to move message from mailbox "A" to mailbox "B".

After a "Seen" flagged message is moved to mailbox "B", I'm getting mailbox "B" info to update "Seen/Unssen" counters: imap_open + imap_mailboxmsginfo - info shows that "Unread" value is increased by 1.

Repeating hole process with N "Seen" flagged messages results in "Unread" value increased by N.

Continuous testing shows - messages are moved successfully, but moved "Seen" flagged messages somehow show up as "Unread" on very first imap_mailboxmsginfo request.

Maybe it makes sence to force flushing some mysterious IMAP buffers, or empty secret IMAP cache, if any ?

Any ideas ? Does actually "Unread/Read" values returned in imap_mailboxmsginfo actually equals to "Unseen/Seen" flags ?

Comment: I haven't used the PHP module, but the python module for IMAP returns flags as a separate entity, if the flags aren't passed to the server on append, then it defaults to "Unread"

Comment: just found kinda hack like solution, just reopen **"To"** mailbox after move/append. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

imap class in php is very buggy, i know it because i wrote my own mail system, and had many problems with imap bugs. You have to stay with your "hack" solution.